# Error: 'read ECONNRESET' unable to retrieve components in vscode

Tags: vs-code

In VS Code, I performed these steps:

1. Ran the command 'SFDX: Create Project with Manifest'.
2. Ran the command 'SFDX: Authorize an Org' and authorized the org.
3. Right-clicked the package.xml file and clicked ' SFDX: Retrieve Source in Manifest from Org'.

After step 3 was completed, the output displayed this-

Starting SFDX: Retrieve Source from Org

read ECONNRESET

I tried by changing version in package.xml from 51.0 to 50.0 and retrieving single helper class from package.xml and also I removed other components from package.xml in case if there is large number of files, creating this issue. Also I restarted the vscode after the changes I made but that also didn't work.

[image]

If anyone has other approach or resolution apart from whatever I already tried please help.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you are behind proxy while using VPN. If yes, update your proxy settings in VS Code.
In VS Code, navigate to (Or simply press **Ctrl**+**,**)

> File > Preferences > Settings

Then under the

> User tab, navigate to Application > Proxy

Add your proxy setting in the field there. Port Number will be 8080 in most cases.

```
Example: http://proxy-XY.COMPANY.com:PORTNUMBER
```

Then make sure **Proxy Strict SSL** is **unchecked**. (You will find it right below the above Proxy input field).

Then make sure the same proxy values are added in your machine.

> Start > Edit the System Environment Variables > (Advanced) >
> Environment Variables.

Add the Variable as **HTTP_PROXY** and Value as **http://proxy-XY.COMPANY.com:PORTNUMBER** in *User Variables*.

In some cases, you might have to add another Variable as **HTTPS_PROXY** and Value as **https://proxy-XY.COMPANY.com:PORTNUMBER** also same as above *in your system alone*.

Then update your SFDX version to the latest version possible. For this, just launch your command prompt and then type **sfdx udpate**. Once it is updated, try restarting your VS Code (your system also if possible) and it should work as expected.

The same steps will work when you get any of the below errors

1. Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
2. read ECONNRESET
3. getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy-XY.COMPANY.com

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this issue sometimes.
check your internet connection.
I changed my connection and it worked.

If that doesn't works then use the cloud icon on the left most panel and try to retrieve the components from there.

Hope it helps